# When removing a package via "apt-get remove", why do you have to (sometimes) upgrade other packages in the process?

Tags: apt

I could give a specific example, but I do think this is a common process and simply do not understand why it is done. Please comment if I should give a specific example when this is happening.

**Edit:**

For the specific example: I tried to remove `apache2` and it tried to upgrade `php5-cgi`, the problem is that the `history.log` in `/var/log/apt/` has not saved this not working attempt. It wasn't working because `apt-get` couldn't upgrade because there was no internet-connection.

The first part of the logged working attempt to remove `apache2` is the following:

```
Log started: 2015-01-24  12:32:00
Selecting previously unselected package php5-cgi.^M
(Reading database ... ^M(Reading database ... 5%^M(Reading database ... 10%^M(Reading database ... 15%^M(Reading database ... 20%^M(Reading database ... 25%^M(Reading database ... 30%^M(Reading database ... 35%^M(Reading database ... 40%^M(Reading database ... 45%^M(Reading database ... 50%^M(Reading database ... 55%^M(Reading database ... 60%^M(Reading database ... 65%^M(Reading database ... 70%^M(Reading database ... 75%^M(Reading database ... 80%^M(Reading database ... 85%^M(Reading database ... 90%^M(Reading database ... 95%^M(Reading database ... 100%^M(Reading database ... 251982 files and directories currently installed.)^M
Preparing to unpack .../php5-cgi_5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5_amd64.deb ...^M
Unpacking php5-cgi (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) ...^M
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...^M
dpkg: libapache2-mod-php5: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:^M
 php5 depends on libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) | libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) | php5-cgi (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) | php5-fpm (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5); however:^M
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 is to be removed.^M
  Package libapache2-mod-php5filter is not installed.^M
  Package php5-cgi is not configured yet.^M
  Package php5-fpm is not installed.
```

So, to restate the question:

When removing a package via `apt-get remove`, why do you have to (sometimes) upgrade other packages in the process?

Comment: Yes, do give a specific example. It is harder to answer things in the abstract.

Comment: Usually, you don't need to upgrade other packages when removing a package. So yes, do give an example.

Comment: This log is a bit too late to know the exact reason, but this is probably due to the `php5 depends on libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) | libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) | php5-cgi (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) | php5-fpm (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5)` rule. The dependency on `libapache2-mod-php5` is no longer satisfied, and `apt-get` tries to satisfy `php5-cgi (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5)`. As said in my answer, the cause is an `A | B` dependency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, this can happen to resolve dependencies, for instance if an installed package depends on `A | B`, you attempt to remove `B`, and `A` is not installed yet or has a too low installed version (in case of versioned dependency). I've already seen something like that.

**Note.** In a particular case, if you want to know why `apt-get` wants to upgrade some package `packageU` when you want to remove package `packageR`, you can try the option `--no-upgrade`:

```
apt-get remove --no-upgrade packageR
```

and see what kind of error message you get (normally an unsatisfied dependency). Alternatively, you can do:

```
apt-get install packageR- packageU=current_version
```

and see the error message (the hyphen after `packageR` means that the package is requested to be removed, and the equal with the current version of `packageU` means that you do not want to upgrade `packageU`), i.e. the unsatisfied dependency. If you do not get an error message and the `packageR` can be removed without upgrading `packageU`, this probably means a bug in the dependency resolution (it is [known to be buggy in some cases](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?dist=unstable;package=apt)).

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand why this is happening.

Comment: @JohnH.K. I've added a note telling what you can do to know why this is happening.